# localization bangla language in grails application in gsp page using properties file

Tags: grails

I need to use localization in my grails application. In my application there will be used two languages. one is English and another one is Bangla. For this, I have installed my desired Bangla font in my pc.

For all other languages it is working fine but in case of Bangla text my gsp page is showing question marks`(????)`.

Note that i have created a new property file named `messages_bn.properties` for bangla text to get value from the file into my gsp page. What am i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure but it might be an issue with your gsp encoding. See if setting these in your config file helps.

grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"

Comment: my config file contains these settings but still does not work.

Comment: another interesting thing is that when i place bangla text in my messages_bn.properties, it does not work. but when i place in the messages_ja.properties, then bangla works. then i change my bangla property file name to messages_bn_BD.properties without any success as well. Is there any naming possibility for bangla property file?

Comment: got the solution. was a problem in creating properties file as there is no option in IntelliJ Idea to create it. just copied one of the existing files and renamed to messages.bn-bd, then it worked.

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel I did the same following you, but no result

Comment: @SumonBappi did you follow the steps mentioned in the comment just above your comment?

Comment: yes, copy and paste message.properties file with name message.bn_bd.properties

Comment: @SumonBappi, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

just encode the file as utf-8. From Intellij I have done following >>

[image]